Can't compile grub from source when "make" command is executed. It can't locate "locale.h", "sys/stat.h" though I have included path to it
I have been trying to build grub from source as part of a learning project. But I can't build it when make command is executed. It shows no errors on running ./bootstrap or ./configure. The following errors are shown after running make :
It was a long error long mostly consisting of missing locale.h and hence I have to cut out a lot of repeating blocks. I know the error is related to some dependency still can't figure out which.


grub-core/lib/zstd/xxhash.c:100:10: fatal error: stdlib.h: No such file or directory
  100 | #include <stdlib.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
grub-core/lib/zstd/zstd_common.c:16:10: fatal error: stdlib.h: No such file or directory
   16 | #include <stdlib.h>      /* malloc, calloc, free */
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
grub-core/lib/zstd/zstd_decompress.c:58:10: fatal error: string.h: No such file or directory
   58 | #include <string.h>      /* memcpy, memmove, memset */
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
In file included from ./include/grub/misc.h:27,
                 from grub-core/kern/i386/backtrace.c:19:
./include/grub/i18n.h:32:12: fatal error: locale.h: No such file or directory
   32 | #  include <locale.h>
      |            ^~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
util/misc.c:21:10: fatal error: errno.h: No such file or directory
   21 | #include <errno.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
In file included from ./include/grub/misc.h:27,
                 from ./include/grub/command.h:25,
                 from grub-core/kern/command.c:22:
./include/grub/i18n.h:32:12: fatal error: locale.h: No such file or directory
   32 | #  include <locale.h>
      |            ^~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
In file included from ./include/grub/misc.h:27,
                 from ./include/grub/disk.h:31,
                 from grub-core/kern/device.c:21:
./include/grub/i18n.h:32:12: fatal error: locale.h: No such file or directory
   32 | #  include <locale.h>
      |            ^~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
In file included from ./include/grub/misc.h:27,
                 from ./include/grub/disk.h:31,
                 from grub-core/kern/disk.c:19:
./include/grub/i18n.h:32:12: fatal error: locale.h: No such file or directory
   32 | #  include <locale.h>
      |            ^~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
In file included from ./include/grub/misc.h:27,
                 from ./include/grub/disk.h:31,
                 from grub-core/lib/disk.c:19:
./include/grub/i18n.h:32:12: fatal error: locale.h: No such file or directory
   32 | #  include <locale.h>
      |            ^~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
util/getroot.c:23:10: fatal error: sys/stat.h: No such file or directory
   23 | #include <sys/stat.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
grub-core/osdep/unix/getroot.c:22:10: fatal error: sys/stat.h: No such file or directory
   22 | #include <sys/stat.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
In file included from grub-core/osdep/getroot.c:2:
grub-core/osdep/linux/getroot.c:22:10: fatal error: sys/stat.h: No such file or directory
   22 | #include <sys/stat.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
In file included from grub-core/osdep/devmapper/getroot.c:22:
./include/grub/emu/getroot.h:25:10: fatal error: sys/types.h: No such file or directory
   25 | #include <sys/types.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
In file included from grub-core/osdep/relpath.c:6:
grub-core/osdep/unix/relpath.c:22:10: fatal error: sys/types.h: No such file or directory
   22 | #include <sys/types.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
In file included from ./include/grub/misc.h:27,
                 from ./include/grub/disk.h:31,
                 from grub-core/kern/emu/hostdisk.c:22:
./include/grub/i18n.h:32:12: fatal error: locale.h: No such file or directory
   32 | #  include <locale.h>
      |            ^~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
In file included from ./include/grub/misc.h:27,
                 from ./include/grub/disk.h:31,
                 from grub-core/osdep/devmapper/hostdisk.c:3:
./include/grub/i18n.h:32:12: fatal error: locale.h: No such file or directory
   32 | #  include <locale.h>
      |            ^~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
In file included from ./include/grub/misc.h:27,
                 from ./include/grub/disk.h:31,
                 from grub-core/osdep/linux/hostdisk.c:22,
                 from grub-core/osdep/hostdisk.c:2:
./include/grub/i18n.h:32:12: fatal error: locale.h: No such file or directory
   32 | #  include <locale.h>
      |            ^~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
In file included from ./include/grub/misc.h:27,
                 from ./include/grub/disk.h:31,
                 from grub-core/osdep/unix/hostdisk.c:22:
./include/grub/i18n.h:32:12: fatal error: locale.h: No such file or directory
   32 | #  include <locale.h>
      |            ^~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
In file included from ./include/grub/misc.h:27,
                 from grub-core/osdep/unix/exec.c:22,
                 from grub-core/osdep/exec.c:2:
./include/grub/i18n.h:32:12: fatal error: locale.h: No such file or directory
   32 | #  include <locale.h>
      |            ^~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
In file included from grub-core/osdep/sleep.c:4:
grub-core/osdep/unix/sleep.c:19:10: fatal error: time.h: No such file or directory
   19 | #include <time.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
In file included from ./include/grub/misc.h:27,
                 from ./include/grub/unicode.h:24,
                 from ./include/grub/term.h:72,
                 from grub-core/osdep/unix/password.c:22,
                 from grub-core/osdep/password.c:4:
./include/grub/i18n.h:32:12: fatal error: locale.h: No such file or directory
   32 | #  include <locale.h>
      |            ^~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
grub-core/kern/emu/misc.c:24:10: fatal error: errno.h: No such file or directory
   24 | #include <errno.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
grub-core/kern/emu/mm.c:24:10: fatal error: stdlib.h: No such file or directory
   24 | #include <stdlib.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
In file included from ./include/grub/misc.h:27,
                 from grub-core/kern/env.c:22:
./include/grub/i18n.h:32:12: fatal error: locale.h: No such file or directory
   32 | #  include <locale.h>
      |            ^~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
In file included from ./include/grub/misc.h:27,
                 from grub-core/kern/err.c:21:
./include/grub/i18n.h:32:12: fatal error: locale.h: No such file or directory
   32 | #  include <locale.h>
      |            ^~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
In file included from ./include/grub/misc.h:27,
                 from grub-core/kern/file.c:20:
./include/grub/i18n.h:32:12: fatal error: locale.h: No such file or directory
   32 | #  include <locale.h>
      |            ^~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
In file included from ./include/grub/misc.h:27,
                 from ./include/grub/disk.h:31,
                 from grub-core/kern/fs.c:20:
./include/grub/i18n.h:32:12: fatal error: locale.h: No such file or directory
   32 | #  include <locale.h>
      |            ^~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
In file included from ./include/grub/misc.h:27,
                 from grub-core/kern/list.c:21:
./include/grub/i18n.h:32:12: fatal error: locale.h: No such file or directory
   32 | #  include <locale.h>
      |            ^~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
In file included from ./include/grub/misc.h:27,
                 from grub-core/kern/misc.c:20:
./include/grub/i18n.h:32:12: fatal error: locale.h: No such file or directory
   32 | #  include <locale.h>
      |            ^~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
In file included from ./include/grub/misc.h:27,
                 from grub-core/kern/partition.c:19:
./include/grub/i18n.h:32:12: fatal error: locale.h: No such file or directory
   32 | #  include <locale.h>
      |            ^~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
In file included from ./include/grub/misc.h:27,
                 from grub-core/lib/crypto.c:21:
./include/grub/i18n.h:32:12: fatal error: locale.h: No such file or directory
   32 | #  include <locale.h>
      |            ^~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
In file included from ./include/grub/misc.h:27,
                 from ./include/grub/dl.h:29,
                 from grub-core/lib/json/json.c:19:
./include/grub/i18n.h:32:12: fatal error: locale.h: No such file or directory
   32 | #  include <locale.h>
      |            ^~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
In file included from ./include/grub/misc.h:27,
                 from ./include/grub/disk.h:31,
                 from ./include/grub/cryptodisk.h:22,
                 from grub-core/disk/luks.c:19:
.o such file or directory
   32 | #  include <locale.h>
      |            ^~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
In file included from ./include/grub/misc.h:27,
                 from ./include/grub/disk.h:31,
                 from ./include/grub/cryptodisk.h:22,
                 from grub-core/disk/cryptodisk.c:19:
./include/grub/i18n.h:32:12: fatal error: locale.h: No such file or directory
   32 | #  include <locale.h>
      |            ^~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
In file included from ./include/grub/misc.h:27,
                 from ./include/grub/dl.h:29,
                 from grub-core/disk/AFSplitter.c:24:
./include/grub/i18n.h:32:12: fatal error: locale.h: No such file or directory
   32 | #  include <locale.h>
      |            ^~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
In file included from ./include/grub/misc.h:27,
                 from grub-core/lib/pbkdf2.c:23:
./include/grub/i18n.h:32:12: fatal error: locale.h: No such file or directory
   32 | #  include <locale.h>
      |            ^~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
In file included from ./include/grub/misc.h:27,
                 from grub-core/commands/extcmd.c:23:
./include/grub/i18n.h:32:12: fatal error: locale.h: No such file or directory
   32 | #  include <locale.h>
      |            ^~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
In file included from ./include/grub/misc.h:27,
                 from grub-core/lib/arg.c:20:
./include/grub/i18n.h:32:12: fatal error: locale.h: No such file or directory
   32 | #  include <locale.h>
      |            ^~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
In file included from ./include/grub/misc.h:27,
                 from ./include/grub/dl.h:29,
                 from grub-core/disk/ldm.c:19:
./include/grub/i18n.h:32:12: fatal error: locale.h: No such file or directory
   32 | #  include <locale.h>
      |            ^~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
In file included from ./include/grub/misc.h:27,
                 from ./include/grub/dl.h:29,
                 from grub-core/disk/diskfilter.c:20:
./include/grub/i18n.h:32:12: fatal error: locale.h: No such file or directory
   32 | #  include <locale.h>
      |            ^~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
In file included from ./include/grub/misc.h:27,
                 from ./include/grub/disk.h:31,
                 from grub-core/partmap/gpt.c:20:
./include/grub/i18n.h:32:12: fatal error: locale.h: No such file or directory
   32 | #  include <locale.h>
      |            ^~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
In file included from ./include/grub/misc.h:27,
                 from ./include/grub/dl.h:29,
                 from ./include/grub/partition.h:22,
                 from grub-core/partmap/msdos.c:20:
./include/grub/i18n.h:32:12: fatal error: locale.h: No such file or directory
   32 | #  include <locale.h>
      |            ^~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
In file included from ./include/grub/misc.h:27,
                 from ./include/grub/disk.h:31,
                 from grub-core/fs/proc.c:20:
./include/grub/i18n.h:32:12: fatal error: locale.h: No such file or directory
   32 | #  include <locale.h>
      |            ^~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminate
      |            ^~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
In file included from ./include/grub/misc.h:27,
                 from grub-core/kern/backtrace.c:19:
./include/grub/i18n.h:32:12: fatal error: locale.h: No such file or directory
   32 | #  include <locale.h>
      |            ^~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make: *** [Makefile:17278: libgrub.pp] Error 1

I have installed every dependency mentioned in the INSTALL file provided in the repo, and have also tried running ./configure with the required efi parameter but it still doesn't compile. locale.h and all other header files are included in usr/include and I have added the required include path in "c_cpp.properties.json" file as well. glibc-devel and glibc-headers are also installed.
Ran the following commands:
./bootstrap
./configure --target=x86_64 --with-platform=efi
make

I am still a college student trying to learn things, and kind helpful gestures are appreciated. Thanks.

Can you post the command -launched by make- which generates theses errors?

https://gist.githubusercontent.com/NikChouhan/179ac788c140185d40caef55ef61dff2/raw/c169924dff4b09ce3b7e037919630a47ea5ac322/Makefile
I am attaching the complete makefle generated as I have limited knowledge about makefiles

You seem not to have a complete C development environment installed.  At minimum, the C standard library headers are not present in the location expected by your compiler.  How you would install the missing components depends on your Linux distribution.
